# WHM Enabling mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have a CentOS 6.8 w/ WHM on GoDaddy and I have a laravel application. The routes don't work, they return a 404 Not found and because of this I'm assuming it's a problem with mod_rewrite.

I cannot seem to find any mod_rewrite anywhere in phpinfo() though I've read it won't appear there because of how cPanel/WHM works. I've tried other commands to show me what the value of mod_rewrite is and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I've also tried adding "RewriteEngine On" in "Home > Service Configuration ?> Apache Configuration > Include Editor". I've googled a lot of pages but I still can't figure out how to do this.

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this btw? I'm having the same issue after moving to a new server.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite comes enabled by default in cPanel
You can use the "http -M" command to verify that Mod_Rewrite is compiled with Apache (it's enabled by default with cPanel):

```
httpd -M|grep rewrite
rewrite_module (shared)
```